# Wordpress plugin is not working after migration to a new server

Tags: wordpress

I have moved my wordpress site to a new server, and login.php is working right.
But in there many plugins is not working well, for example the login page is not linked to any other page after I submitted my username and password.

Here is the login page link:
https://cpalocate.ca/login/

I have entered the invalid username and password, it will also show the blank page, but not error page.

When I add this code in wp-config.php

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
```

it showed this text. " Notice: Constant WYZ_THEME_DIR already defined in /home/.....".

And I have fixed that, but the same problem.

Now there is no any error debug, but the login page is also not working.

I changed the php version of my site in cpanel, but the same.
Anyone has your idea to solve this issue?

Comment: It is very had to answer it like this, you will need to post more specific information like: what plugin are you using, code examples if you added something custom and so on?

Comment: @Clarenceli I've updated the answer I gave.  Either your theme is bad, or you have a bad plugin.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible (I'd even say likely) that on your old server it was using PHP 5.6 (or at least a different version of PHP than your new server) and now you're on 7.0, 7.2 or even 7.3.  It would seem that if that's the case, some of your plugins are incompatible.

You should edit your wp-config.php and add

`define('WP_DEBUG', true);`

so that you can see the errors on your screen, at least until you figure out which plugins are causing the problems.

If it is a matter of PHP version, check with your host to see if they can roll you back, or you'll have to either contact the plugin author and have them update the plugins, or you need to fix the code yourself, based on whatever the error messages you see are.

Edit: if this doesn't solve your problem, first try a default WordPress theme like twenty-nineteen or whatever. If that doesn't solve it, then disable each plugin one at a time until you find the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

I have turned off all my plugins and turn back it one by one.

I have found one of my plugins is caused this problem, it is PM Pro Settings.

So I deactivated it and there is no any problem now.

I am using other plugins on behalf of that one.